# Forgot password works in development, not production. Rails 4 auth from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, forgot-password

Is there a way to make my forgot password work without having to use a Gem? I've already setup the users and everything to my liking from scratch. When I'm in my production app I enter everything as if I forgot my password, and it tells me my password was sent, but doesn't show up.

Heroku Logs:

```
 2014-04-14T01:03:32.595045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/password_resets/new host=boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com request_id=2b759363-24f6- 4053-87f4-81c62b98374c fwd="162.232.157.38" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=21ms status=304  bytes=807
2014-04-14T01:03:32.578274+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/password_resets/new" for  162.232.157.38 at 2014-04-14 01:03:32 +0000
2014-04-14T01:03:32.578213+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/password_resets/new" for  162.232.157.38 at 2014-04-14 01:03:32 +0000
2014-04-14T01:03:30.919303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/login  host=boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com request_id=6b2c98d1-a2cc-4294-bdd3-a66d34f54572  fwd="162.232.157.38" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=29ms status=304 bytes=847
2014-04-14T01:03:42.538025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST  path=/password_resets host=boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com request_id=db763e58-ae0e-46e9-bf86-b930932c94c3 fwd="162.232.157.38" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=74ms status=302 bytes=1167
2014-04-14T01:03:42.640229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/  host=boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com request_id=8579ce48-075a-48c6-976e-2a5a6b9460c9  fwd="162.232.157.38" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=5316
2014-04-14T01:03:42.520887+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/password_resets" for  162.232.157.38 at 2014-04-14 01:03:42 +0000
2014-04-14T01:03:42.520899+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/password_resets" for  162.232.157.38 at 2014-04-14 01:03:42 +0000
2014-04-14T01:03:42.627901+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 162.232.157.38 at  2014-04-14 01:03:42 +0000
2014-04-14T01:03:42.627964+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 162.232.157.38 at 2014-04-14 01:03:42 +0000
johns-mbp:Jetpack johncurry$
```

production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com/" }

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = 
  {

   :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
   :port               => 587,
   :domain             => 'gmail.com', #you can also use google.com
   :authentication     => :plain,
   :user_name          => 'myemail@gmail.com',
   :password           => 'Gmailpasswordhere'
  }
```

however, when I use Localhost, it works fine.

development logs:

```
Started GET "/password_resets/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-13 18:50:19 -0600
Processing by PasswordResetsController#new as HTML
      Rendered password_resets/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)

          [1m[35mCategory Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
          Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.2ms)
          Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
        Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 14.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started POST "/password_resets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-13 18:50:27 -0600
Processing by PasswordResetsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5Sy0bTXcSU8ndvQUj21dKEP1h7gVtfXtiefqrrydydA=", "email"=>"john.steven.curry@gmail.com", "commit"=>"Reset Password"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'john.steven.curry@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."password_reset_token" = '7ImtuiJmf7G_LksyoC8Ftg' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'Curry' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'john.steven.curry@gmail.com' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (19.7ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "password_reset_token" = ?, "password_reset_sent_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1   [["password_reset_token", "7ImtuiJmf7G_LksyoC8Ftg"], ["password_reset_sent_at", Mon, 14 Apr  2014 00:50:27 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 14 Apr 2014 00:50:27 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (1.4ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendered user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb (0.7ms)

Sent mail to john.steven.curry@gmail.com (11.4ms)
Date: Sun, 13 Apr 2014 18:50:27 -0600
From: john.steven.curry@gmail.com
To: john.steven.curry@gmail.com
Message-ID: <534b30d3ec249_2bda3ff2e297e6a845448@johns-mbp.mail>
Subject: Password Reset
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

To reset your password, click the URL below.

http://localhost:3000/password_resets/7ImtuiJmf7G_LksyoC8Ftg/edit

If you did not request your password to be reset, just ignore this email and your password will continue to stay the same. Have a great day!
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 821ms (ActiveRecord: 21.8ms)
```

development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full url in your production.rb file.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "boiling-garden-2168.herokuapp.com" }
```

Try to use SendGrid as a transactional mailer. It's a heroku add-on.

```
heroku addons:add sendgrid
```

Then, check to make sure the keys have been added to the heroku config.

```
heroku config
```

Then change your `config/environment.rb` code to something like this:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MyApp::Application.initialize!

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
   :port           => '587',
   :authentication => :plain,
   :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
   :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
   :domain         => 'heroku.com',
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. I've edited it like you've suggested, and nothing has changed. It seems like in my log file nothing is happening at all. I'm wondering if it's even processing the request to send the email. Look at my original question I have changed my production.rb file

Comment: Do you have a transactional mail add-on setup? You need to set up SendGrid or a mailing system in heroku.

Comment: Not that I know of. Will SendGrid work for heroku? If not, what is your recommendation for a mailer in Heroku?? I'm trying to not use something that requires me to change all my user registration and login setup etc.. since I already have it to my liking..

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a shot, but my acct is still being verified so I can't send any emails just yet. Got it set up will try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: no, It didn't work. It's extremely frustrating. I'm going to come back to it later, It should not be this stupidly difficult when there is a rails cast video and a company that gets paid to simplify this. I've got the send grid on there, nothing at all happens. The logs don't even seem like they are doing any emailing at all. It doesn't just fail, it's like heroku fails to even try..

Comment: I have that setup in my app. Maybe we are missing something.

Well, I don't have it in the production.rb file. I have it in the environment.rb file. I changed my answer to reflect what I have.

Comment: Just read the docs. The documentation says place it in config/environment.rb: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

Comment: Dude I've read the docs, and I have followed the docs to the T. They don't work. I'm guessing there must be errors because I was following the rails casts tutorial on this which worked only in development. In the cast he didn't give instructions for setting up the production, and there must be conflicting code maybe? But I followed the docs. I've followed several different docs.

Comment: That probably didn't come off right. I was saying "I just read the docs"...Sorry I can't help. Has the log output changed at all?

Comment: That is correct, the log has not changed regardless of what I do to any of these files. I have a friend who has mailers set up so I'll post the answer in a while when I get the answer. Sorry for my last comment too, I'm not the most patient person I probably should have chosen a different hobby, like knitting.